# How to copy other column's value as default value for a new column in rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I have a model with a column `price`. I need to add a new_column `marked_price` having value of `price` as it's default value. Can I write this in my migration, or what could be the best way to do this?

Something like:

```
class AddMarkedPriceToMenuItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :menu_items, :marked_price, :decimal, :default => :price
  end
end
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, the database does not allow you to do this using the `DEFAULT` setting on a table column.

But you can do it using an *ActiveRecord* callback

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_market_price_default

  private

  def set_market_price_default
    self.market_price = self.price
  end
end
```

As for the migration itself, you can update `market_price` manually

```
def change
  add_column :menu_items, :marked_price, :decimal

  reversible do |dir|
    dir.up { MenuItem.update_all('marked_price = price') }
  end
end
```

Note that you might want to create a copy of the model that sits locally in the migration, so that it doesn't go out of sync in the future.

Comment: I think you got "price" and "marked_price" the wrong way.

This syntax `MenuItem.update_all(price: :market_price)` doesn't work (at least on ActiveRecord 4.2.7.1) and should be `MenuItem.update_all("marked_price = price")`

Comment: Also, the `update_all` only needs to be executed when migrating up (not down). It could be wrapped in a `reversible` block 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-reversible

Comment: @WizardofOgz you're right on all counts. I have updated my answer. Thank you.

Comment: It is a bad practice to reference your model classes in a migration, since your migrations could be executed after your model class has changed / been deleted.

Comment: @JeffTsay I don't quite understand your concern. Of necessity, a migration refers to at least one model class, the one the migration is being applied to, so why would it be dangerous to refer to it in another way in the same migration? If the migration is being applied after the model class has been deleted, then surely the problem lies not with the migration itself, but with it being executed out-of-order?

Comment: @TeemuLeisti, Jeff has a point. In a real world scenario you want to take a snapshot of your model and put it in the migration.

Comment: WARNING: Don't use application logic in DB migrations. 
https://jakeyesbeck.com/2021/04/10/avoid-models-in-migrations/

Answer (score 0):

This is a General way of solving, without the need for Writing Query, as queries are subjected to risk.

```
class Demo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :events, :time_zone, :string
    Test.all.each do |p|
      p.update_attributes(time_zone: p.check.last.time_zone)
    end
    remove_column :sessions, :time_zone
  end
end
```

Comment: Again, the Test model could be deleted by the time you run this migration, so better to redefine it here or use native SQL.

Comment: WARNING: Don't use application logic in DB migrations. jakeyesbeck.com/2021/04/10/avoid-models-in-migrations